# Get an empty list of XPATH expression in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have watched a video at this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EELySnTPeyw and this is the code ( I have changed the xpath as it seems the website has been changed)

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

def get_results(search_term):
    url = 'https://www.startpage.com'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
    browser.get(url)
    search_box = browser.find_element_by_id('q')
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    try:
        links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'w-gl__result-title')]")
    except:
        links = browser.find_lemets_by_xpath("//h3//a")
    print(links)
    for link in links:
        href = link.get_attribute('href')
        print(href)
        results.append(href)
    browser.close()

get_results('cat')
```

The code works well as for the part of opening the browser and navigating to the search box and sending keys but as for the `links` return an empty list although I have manually searched for the xpath in the developer tools and it returns 10 results.

Comment: consider using proper webdriverwaits here.  Seems like a javascript DOM update so Selenium will not wait.  (find_elements is running before the search results return...)  Also if this doesn't live update on keystrokes, you probably need to send the enter key or click a submit button.

Comment: Can you show me how to fix that?

Comment: You are sending keys (search term) but you are not clicking search button. This is probably why you don't have any link available.
`submit_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="search"]/button")[0]`
then `submit_button.click()`. And after getting results - try to get links.

Comment: I do not see the  search_box = browser.find_element_by_id('q') this search box on 'https://www.startpage.com', I am blid, can someone help me to se it. Ha ha ha.:-)

Comment: @PiotrGrędowski Thanks a lot. You have spotted the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add keys.enter to your search. You weren't on the next page.

```
search_box.send_keys(search_term+Keys.ENTER)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Outputs

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat
https://www.cat.com/en_US.html
https://www.cat.com/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbP2N1BQdYc
https://icatcare.org/advice/thinking-of-getting-a-cat/
https://www.caterpillar.com/en/brands/cat.html
https://www.petfinder.com/cats/
https://www.catfootwear.com/US/en/home
https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/cat-care/general-cat-care
https://www.britannica.com/animal/cat
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I missed an important line `search_box.submit()` and I think this is equal to pressing on Enter key.

Comment: They are equal.